Membership Types form - selection fields show on underlying page not the form in focus
When I try to setup a Membership type, the dialog box comes up but those fields which have selection boxes (e.g. Membership Organisation) appear out of focus on the underlying page.
I'm trying to get started with version 5.74.1 in a hosted Wordpress 6.5.4 installation.

Possible to share some screenshots?

just posted an example screenshot

sorry but you will need to repaste the s/shot in to the Question, not as an Answer as it will get deleted.

see the drop down behind the dialog box in focus - after moving the dialog box to the right to reveal the bug!


Looks like Themeing issue, can you try switching the theme

I prefer to stick with our current theme - not had to change it for any other plugin - and don't want to break anything on an established live site.

i think Pradeep is suggesting you 'try switching' in order to confirm this is the issue.

Same thing happens with the Send Email to Contact dialog box, any drop down gets lost behind the dialog box in focus - in this screen shot I've moved the email dialog box to the left to reveal the 'hidden' drop downs:


Hi Nick - repeating my earlier comment that adding new info as an Answer isn't a good way to go as the Answer will get deleted, or converted to a comment, both of which result in loss of the screenshot. pls EDIT your QUESTION to update with the screenshots. (Any reason this is not possible for you)

If I right-click on the 'Add Membership Type' button and open in a new tab it works as expected.
I see form posts in the old archived forum that this is not new problem.
I presume it's a JavaScript problem - but I don't have a clue how to find out what the actual cause it is ...
Any ideas? Or do I just give up and look for another membership CRM ...

again not an answer so likely to be deleted. there is a setting so that you can turn off the pop-up. never seen this problem which therefore opens the question about what theme you are using etc etc or whether there is some other plugin that isn't playing nicely

I'd be interested where to find that setting - it's not very good for a plugin's UI to fail so miserably to interact with WP themes (if that is the problem). It seems that the implementation of CiviCRM on WordPress is bit of a kludge ..
